# Microsoft Access can't append all the records in the append query

Tags: ms-access-2013

I found numerous threads online about my problem but the I'm very new to access and therefore it's hard to understand.

I'm having the following problem with my Access Database.

Microsoft Access set 0 fields to Null due to a type of conversion failure, and it didn't add 0 records to the table due to key violations, 0 records due lock violations, and 0 records due to validation rule violations. Do you want to run query anyway?

I'm using Acces 2013.And I have imported SharePoint List Data in Access 2013.

Here Following is My Query

**INSERT INTO [Content Metadata Master] ([Content Name], [Metadata Name], [Value])
SELECT Content.Name as [Content Name], 'Author 1' as [Metadata Name] , [Gold Metadata].[Author 1] as Value1
FROM Content, [Gold Metadata]
WHERE ((([Gold Metadata].[Case Number])='OM-0057' And ([Gold Metadata].[Case Number])=[Content].[Name]));**

Can anyone please help me explain in baby language how this problem occurs and how to resolve it without losing data.

Many Thanks,

Samadhan

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the exact structure is of the data coming in, and the table accepting it, it's impossible to give a complete answer.  But your problem is, "due to a type of conversion failure".  This means that one or more of your values are not of the same type.

This means, you are trying to insert a string into a number field, or a date into a boolean, etc, etc...

Something is inconsistent between what you are pushing in, and what is trying to accept it.

Check the data types.

Comment: When I use only Select Query that time it displays the output .

But , When I add insert command in it that time it will give an error.

because [Gold Metadata] and [Content] Tables are from different SharePoint Server, 

 [Gold Metadata] is from SharePoint 2007 and [Content] is from SharePoint 2013.

So I want to migrate this 2007 to 2013. So have connected this is in access.

Any solution for it.

Thanks ,

Samadhan

Comment: Right - the SELECT will work because it's just reading.  But your insert is trying to write the values.  You may not be able to do a direct import like that.  You could try exporting the tables from Sharepoint, then doing an Import to Access.  You may have better results that way.